# Upgrading to Angular 5, splitHash error

Tags: typescript, npm, angular-cli, package.json, angular5

I am currently in the process of upgrading from Angular 4.x to 5.x and have been running into the following error:

```
main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: i.splitHash is not a function
at Object.t.parseUrl (main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1)
at t.path (main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1)
at e.<anonymous> (main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1)
at e.V9yc.t.UrlRouter.e.sync (main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1)
at bs (main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1)
at main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1
at vt (main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1)
at main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1
at new e (main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1)
at Object.Dt [as createNgModuleRef] (main.81bcdf404dc22078865d.bundle.js:1)
```

If I do an 'ng lint' I pass, 'ng build --prod' I pass, 'ng serve' I pass. But when I do an 'ng serve --prod' I get this error at runtime and I cannot figure out what is causing it. I thought it may be a ui-router version issue but upgrading to `"@uirouter/angular": "1.0.0-rc.1"` (and all versions below it) didn't do anything. Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Comment: I will post a resolution if we find one. But for now we are staying on angular 4 until we can figure out the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried again to upgrade, and this time it worked. I imagine that I wasn't upgrading all my libraries correctly.

I believe I was still trying to use the angular libraries like animations, cdk, common, etc. at 2.0.0-beta.12 when I was getting this error. Now they are at 5.1.0 and seem to be working perfectly.